# Why is it that TCP packets can be modified to block invalid packets, but not UDP packets

Tags: iptables, firewall, tcp, udp, packet

On a random day I was googling `iptables` rules to harden my desktop, and came across this post[1]. At some point the guide mentions blocking invalid TCP packets using tcp-modules with these rules;

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP`

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP`

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP`

I pressed return on the above commands and the rules were applied successfully. Then I tried replacing the `tcp` portions on each of the commands with `udp` for eg, in case of the 3rd command I'd do,

`iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp ! --udp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP`

Which returned me an error saying these rules are not valid for udp packets. I am on a Debian OS, Kernel version 4.9.x

The article I was reading online

1. https://www.booleanworld.com/depth-guide-iptables-linux-firewall/

Comment: Also see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_way_handshake).

Comment: UDP is a  little like throwing a stone over a wall and then walk away. UDP is datagram so one single blob while TCP is a stream (ie like a stream of water.)  The other thing is that TCP uses a three-state protocol to establish  and verifying integrity of transfer including notifying if something is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a stateful protocol, UDP is stateless, so you cannot use `ctstate` with it.

Either you let traffic for a particular port for UDP or you don't.

Also `--udp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN` is just pure nonsense.

In short familiarize yourself with TCP/IP and UDP a bit before rushing to set up iptables.

Comment: One can use `--ctstate` with UDP packets. That's how one allows for example a DNS reply to a DNS query using  `-m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED`. conntrack keeps a state *also* for UDP. Of course the rest is correct.

Comment: @A.B I'm not sure `--ctstate` for `UDP` packets actually works - have you tested it?

Comment: Of course, did you?

Comment: I haven't as I've no idea how it can be tested in the first place especially for services which use protocols other than what's known and can be easily tested, e.g. DNS.

Comment: Just know that conntrack keeps udp (or icmp or any other protocol) states just like tcp. The difference is that the state is destroyed only with a timeout (initially 30s then more if traffic was seen both directions), while, still in conntrack's point of view, tcp's connection can be closed by a valid tcp fin or tcp rst. tcp's timeout once established, defaults to several days, so it's rarely the cause of the end of a connection state in conntrack.

Comment: In other words connection tracking for UDP looks like a gimmick and it doesn't necessarily protect against port scanning or any other attacks.